# zsh: Halt when command not found

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, subshell, shell-builtin

I want to stop the zsh script running when it encounters a command not found error.

I know of `command_not_found_handler`, but this function only allows me to print a message, not halt the parent shell.

The functionality I am looking for is similar to when a glob match fails:

```bsh
echo nonexistent*
echo this will not be shown
```

```
zsh: no matches found: nonexistent*
```

Comment: Note that `cmd nonexistent*` only exits the shell if `cmd` is builtin.

Comment: `set -e` / `set -o errexit`? with all the caveats it has...

Comment: @ikkachu I don't want to exit the shell on all errors, just when a command is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a [`ZERR` trap](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-trap) to get finer control than what `set -e` allows. Conventionally, the exit status 127 is reserved for command-not-found errors.

```
trap 'if (($? == 127)); then exit 127; fi' ZERR
```

This has the same caveats as `set -e`. In particular, it won't trigger inside a conditional such as `if no_such_command; …`. And it can only exit from the current subshell, not from the original shell (but it will trigger the parent shell's ZERR trap if applicable).

---

I have a hard time imagining circumstances where the behavior you're asking for would be desirable. Use `set -e`. For the specific commands where a failure is expected, append `|| true`.

Comment: If I had known about `set -e` when I started scripting, I would have used it. Now, however, I would need to refactor tons of stuff to get them to work this way.

Comment: I have added some code to the zerr trap to ask the user if they want to halt or not; The problem is that the trap is triggered multiple (five) times on a single command not found error. Any ideas?

Comment: @HappyFace The trap is triggered once per failing command. If you don't understand what your script is doing, post a new question with a [small, complete script that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).